# Add a class to a paragraph node in TipTap

Tags: javascript, tiptap

I'm stuck trying to accomplish what I'd imagine is a very simple task in TipTap 2.0. I'm trying to add a class to a selected paragraph. The code I'm trying is below:

```
this.editor.chain().focus().updateAttributes('paragraph', {class:'lead'});
```

I want this to be editable per paragraph. I don't want all paragraphs to have the same class added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some further investigation, I have found a solution for this. My initial assumption was incorrect. I thought that you use updateAttributes to directly add a class to the paragraph. But you need to extend Paragraph with your own 'class' attribute, then you can amend the HTML using renderHTML.

```
const CustomParagraph = Paragraph.extend({
            addAttributes() {
                return {
                    class: {
                        default: null,
                        // Take the attribute values
                        renderHTML: attributes => {
                            // … and return an object with HTML attributes.
                            return {
                                class: `${attributes.class}`,
                            }
                        },
                    },
                }
            },
        })

this.editor = new Editor({
            element: this.tiptapEditorTarget,
            extensions: [
                CustomParagraph,
            ],
        });

this.editor.commands.updateAttributes('paragraph', {class:'lead'});
```

Comment: I was trying to do what the [docs suggested](https://tiptap.dev/api/nodes/paragraph#html-attributes), but it appears maybe this isn't possible with `Paragraph`?  Your suggestion here did work, but it seems like maybe Paragraph's configure has a bug.

Comment: Actually, I figured out my issue... I had to do the configure in the extensions... so it'd look something like this `extensions: [ StarterKit.configure({ paragraph: { HTMLAttributes: { class: 'my-class' } } }) ]`